# How to use window.load in React native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I have a simple button on my page, I'm using Expo / React Native.

I want to navigate to a page using a classic window.open when I press the button. However, when I click the button, I get "undefined is not a function."

As mentioned, I am using Expo router, however I can't open a random URL with Expo router, it has to be a created route.

Can anyone explain why this is not working even though window is defined through JavaScript?

[image]

Comment: why not use Linking API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React Native, there is no concept of "window" like in web browsers. React Native runs on mobile platforms like iOS and Android natively without a browser window.
To open a new page in React Native, you need to use the routing/navigation library, like React Navigation.
Instead of `window.open`, you would do something like:

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

function MyComponent() {

  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const handlePress = () => {
    navigation.navigate('SomeScreen'); 
  }

  return (
    <Button onPress={handlePress} title="Go to some screen"/>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. The way you recommended is actually the correct way to do static navigation too. 

For anyone else who runs across this, I was misinformed. You can navigate to a static page using the router like so:

router.push("https://www.google.com");